# Set start_url dynamic in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Trying to create PWA but the manifest.json request to set an url in start_url, but we have 27 different pages we want it to work on. Is there a way to populate start_url dynamic with the url the user is?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start URL should only be the bit you have blocked out in red, what you may consider the "home page" or "base page" of your website. For example, Google's 'start_url' would be `https://google.com`.

This is the URL a user would come to when they first start your PWA, or have finished a line of visit and want to go back to the start of the site.

See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url

Comment: Thanks, but I get this point, however we have 27 different pages that we want to open individually. Will I have to create 27 different manifest.json?

Comment: Probably, yeah. You could dynamically generate them, but it's not massively reliable: https://dev.to/pablo_74/pwa-set-manifest-json-name-icon-dynamically-client-side-jabbadabbadoo-10h7